# Very High Training Accuracy and very low Testing Accuracy CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, overfitting, train

I'm using 3 layer CNN with 8, 16, and 32 filters, each of size 5 X 5. I'm getting an training accuracy of 99.97%. Testing accuracy of 41.11%.

Total classes: 605

Train Set: Each class has 7 samples

Test Set: Each class has 1 sample.

Is the ratio of train and test set causing the huge difference in the train and test accuracy?

Comment: Can you share the some more information regarding your model?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Conv->Relu->MaxPool->Conv->ReLU->MaxPool->Conv->ReLU->MaxPool

Comment: You can try using LeakyReLU layers and Dropout layers.